# Nginx how to show IP blocked page?

Tags: nginx, proxypass, ip-blocking

I have a config like this for my *Nginx* server:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/domain.csr;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/domain.key;

  server_name ~^(\w+)\.(\w+)$ ;

  location / {
    rewrite ^\/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass https://my-app.ondigitalocean.app/ ;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  error_page 444 =200 @unavailable.html;
  location = @unavailable.html {
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    proxy_pass https://myapp.ondigitalocean.app/unavailable.html;
    allow all;
  }

  if ($allowed_country = no) {
    return 444;
  }
}
```

It works fine, but I can't get `unavailable.html` page I allocated at the remote server (see `proxy_pass`), my error log shows:

```
 [error] 20#20: *1 could not find named location "@unavailable.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: ~^(\w+)\.(\w+)$
```

What I'm missing? Is it even possible?
Or I have to copy-paste such page to *Nginx* home?

Comment: But should this  error_page 444 =200 change it back to 200? Besided I've checked it with 403 error code result the same I cant see the page

Comment: Why not I want to send my own custom page this has nothing to do with laws. So I need a body with 200 at the end just one custom page for the blocked countries. So the question isn't about HTTP error code because with different code I have also no page

Comment: I edited your comment below into your question - thank you for providing the error, now it is much clearer where exactly you are stuck. I think my updated question should now get you at least one step towards a working configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `=` equals prefix in *named locations* (indicated by the `@` at sign). Those are always *exact* matches anyway - and are not prefixed like regular URIs, as shown in the two distinct [syntax descriptions for `location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
location [ = | ~ | ~* | ^~ ] uri { ... }
location @name { ... }
```

You can then force the path passed to your upstream to be the one you want:

```
location @unavailable.html {
  rewrite ^ /unavailable.html break;
  proxy_pass https://myapp.ondigitalocean.app;
}
```

The [*Nginx* docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) actually recommend not putting the URI into the `proxy_pass` directive here; emphasis mine:

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined: When location is specified using a regular expression, and also **inside named locations**.
> In these cases, proxy_pass should be **specified without a URI**.

Side note: You should *not* use `return 444` unless you want the special behaviour *Nginx* assigns to that value. You should also *not* return a status code `200` unless you successfully return the requested resource.

If you have made the resource *unavailable* for your sites visitor based on the country you suspect him browsing from, return a code specific to the reason you made that so (typically [`403 Forbidden`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) or [`451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451))

Comment: But how it should work with IF section?

Comment: Actually I've got this  ```      [error] 20#20: *1 could not find named location "@unavailable.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: ~^(\w+)\.(\w+)$,

Comment: Oh just remove that extra `=` equals sign (just `location @unavailable.html`), you actually want a *named location* as nginx already guessed from you using the `@` at sign in the `error_page`

Comment: actually @ never works for location section I have error. ginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block i

Comment: actually it doesnt matter about location. All I want show specific error page if IP is blocked.